# Java. Estimation of total number of printing pages

Tags: java, printing

I have question how to check how many pages will be printed when i use my own `Printable` class.
I need it, because i want to have "page_number/total_pages" in footer of each page.
In my case problem with estimation of rows is that rows are wrapped. Additionaly the are  empty rows beetwen some of the lines of text and there are some other cases which can prevent regular spreading of text. Generally this is not uniform printing.
As you know, rendering process is done after calling all print dialog windows.
Is any way to deal with this issue or should i somehow launch printing simulation , to receieve real number of pages? Or maybe should i implement some other class?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Maybe this is no elegant, but it works (i tested estimation with document with 1200 pages and estimation is accurate).
 I will show you rather concept supported with couple line of code because my `Printable` classes are complex.
This is class which calls all operations connected with printing:

```
package print_manager;

import icd_searcher.ResultContainer;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import others.MeasuredBox;


public class PrintManager
{
    private PrinterJob printerJob;
    private SimpleResultPrinter srp;


    /**
     * Print printable object.
     * 
     * @param toPrint
     */
    public void initPrint(ResultContainer resultToPrint)
    {
        printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        PageFormat selectedArea = printerJob.pageDialog(printerJob.defaultPage());
        MeasuredBox margin = new MeasuredBox(new Point((int) selectedArea.getImageableX(), (int) selectedArea.getImageableY()), (int) selectedArea.getImageableWidth(), (int) selectedArea.getImageableHeight() - 72);
        srp = new SimpleResultPrinter(resultToPrint, margin);

        SimpleResultPrinterSimulator srpSimulation = new SimpleResultPrinterSimulator(resultToPrint, margin);

        // total pages simulation
        int totalPages = 0;
        try
        {
            while (srpSimulation.print(selectedArea, totalPages) != Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE)
            {
                totalPages++;
            }
        }
        catch (PrinterException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        printerJob.setPrintable(srp, widenedPage);

        if (printerJob.printDialog())
        {
            try
            {
                printerJob.print();
            }
            catch (PrinterException exc)
            {
                System.out.println(exc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method print in `SimpleResultPrinter`

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat page, int pageIndex) throws 
PrinterException {...}
```

Method print in `SimpleResultPrinterSimulator`

```
public int print(PageFormat page, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException
    {...}
```

You need to know about this:
`MeasuredBox` and `ResultContainer` are my custom classes that have no meaning in this conception - treat them as a "some classes".
Class `SimpleResultPrinter` which is `Printable` has method `print(...)` which is called by `printerJob.print()`.
`SimpleResultPrinterSimulator` has the same method `print(...)` like `SimpleResultPrinter` except there is no draw actions in it for better performance and of course `SimpleResultPrinterSimulator` has only this method. Also `SimpleResultPrinterSimulator` extends `Component` because i need Graphics object to measure font height.
My solution is just to launch simulation of printing and `print(...)` makes the same actions like will be done soon during printing except of real drawing to any `Graphics` object. Finally i recieves total number of pages.
I know this is not elegant and i make the same action twice (lost of performance), but i don't see any other way to estimate number of pages in complex printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to get no. of pages:

```
int linesPerPage;        // No. of lines per Page to be drawn.
static int numPages;     // No. of pages too be rendered.

public int getNumberOfPages()   // Override method to get Number Of Pages.
{
     return numPages;
}
```

in main..

```
    linesPerPage = (int)Math.floor(format.getImageableHeight()/linespacing);
    numPages = (DATA_to_Print.length - 1)/linesPerPage + 1;
```

in override print method..

```
    if ((pagenum < 0) | (pagenum >= numPages)) 
    {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
```

Each time when print method will be call, value of the numPages will increment.